# SASS invalid property value

Tags: angular, sass, storybook

I try to use a Font in Storybook, but i get in Chrome the failure invalid property value. Im totally new to sass and storybook.

Error-Img:
https://ibb.co/HqFLJ5H

Main Sass File (code shortened):

```
@import './src/assets/sass/color.sass'
@import './src/assets/sass/font.sass'

.flex-container
  display: -webkit-flex
  display: flex
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap
  flex-flow: row wrap
  padding: $cube

.flex-item
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto
  flex: 1 0 auto

p
  font: $font-normal
  size: $font-size-large
```

Font Sass File (code shortened):

```
@font-face
    font-family: 'Verdana'
    src: url('src/assets/font/Verdana.ttf')

$font-normal: Verdana
```

Here the HTML of the component.

```
     <div class="flex-item">
    <h1>Letter</h1>
    <p>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
        <p>1234567890</p>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
    <p>!"§$%&/()=?"</p>
    </div>
```

How can I use this font? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`font` is a shorthand form which requires more values than only the `font-family`

From [CSS - font | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font):

> If font is specified as a shorthand for several font-related properties, then:
>
> it must include values for:
>
> - `<font-size>`
> - `<font-family>`

So either use

```
p
  font: $font-size-large $font-normal
```

or

```
p
  font-family: $font-normal
  font-size: $font-size-large
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `@font-face` declares font family, try to use `font-family` property instead of `font`

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'Verdana'
  src: url('src/assets/font/Verdana.ttf')

$font-normal: 'Verdana'

p
 font-family: $font-normal, serif
 size: $font-size-large
```

Comment: While this answer is correct, it does not tell the reasonm why it works this way. Look at my answer, if you want to know why.

Comment: @yunzen I agree, that your answer gives better explanation. That's why I voted up.